# timer pop up wont stop looping when time is up

Tags: javascript, button, timer

trying to create a timer that starts when button is clicked and send a pop up when time is up on my game

I have tried breaking the loop but when this happens pop up no longer appears

````
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function (){
  var oneMinute = 60,
  display = document.querySelector('.timer');
  startTimer(oneMinute, display);
  render();

});

function startTimer(duration, display){
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function (){
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
          render();
      })

      if (--timer <= 0) {
          timer = "0.00";
          clearInterval(timer);
          swal.fire(`YOU FAILED FINAL SCORE ${points}`)
      } 



  }, 1000)


};

render();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here `var timer = duration` and here `clearInterval(timer)`.

`duration` is a parameter and not an interval ID which `clearInterval` requires that's set by `setInterval`.

So really you want to reference the interval and clear by the same reference.

```
var interval = setInterval(function (){
  ...
}, 1000);
```

Replace your `clearInterval(timer);` with `clearInterval(interval);`